# Sublime Text 3 "Package Control Can't Be Found"

Tags: macos, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3 Build 3083 and I just opened up the app today and tried to use some packages I installed and none of them seemed to be working. When I listed the packages and tried to open one (Package Control for example) I see the error “Package Control can’t be found.”

This is happening with all of the packages in my Installed Packages folder `/Users/me/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages` Has anyone experienced this and if so how can it be fixed? Thanks!